# Show Generic Value in cell with a value that doesn't fit

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a License # tracking worksheet with headers - State Named columns "AK,AL,AR" and Issued and Expired Date columns that follow each state. i.e., AL | Al Issued | Al Expired

The default view is to have the State Names visible at ColumnWidth = 5 and the Issued and Expired Columns hidden. In Client rows, the License # is too big to fit into the 5 wide cells. The values overflow the column boundaries and look a mess.

I'm looking for a macro that Shows the State License numbers' as "##" (or something generic, maybe a color) when the ColumnWidth = 5 but shows the real value when the column is expanded to ColumnWidth = 13.

Here are my Hide and Unhide subs. The License numbers are in Column WS.Cells(5,i - 1)

```
Sub HideStates()
Dim lc As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim dRng As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("License Details")
lc = Range("A5").End(xlToRight).Column
lr = Range("A6").End(xlDown).row


For i = 6 To lc
row = 6

    If WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Issued*" Or WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Expires*" Then
    
        If WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Issued*" Then
     
            WS.Cells(5, i - 1).ColumnWidth = 5
     
            WS.Range(Cells(row, i - 1), Cells(lr, i - 1)).Select
            
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If Cells(row, i - 1).Value <> "" Then
                    ActiveCell = Replace("###", "*", 1)
                    End If
                    row = row + 1
                Next cell
        
        End If
          
     If WS.Cells(5, i - 1).Value Like "**SPL*" Then WS.Cells(5, i - 1).ColumnWidth = 6

            If dRng Is Nothing Then
            Set dRng = WS.Cells(1, i)
        Else
            Set dRng = Union(dRng, WS.Cells(1, i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
    dRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    Call ScrollToTop 
End If
End Sub

Sub UnhideStates()
Dim lc As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim dRng As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("License Details")

For i = 6 To 164
    If WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Issued*" Or WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Expires*" Then
    
     If WS.Cells(5, i).Value Like "*Issued*" Then WS.Cells(5, i - 1).ColumnWidth = 13 
     
        If dRng Is Nothing Then
            Set dRng = WS.Cells(1, i)
        Else
            Set dRng = Union(dRng, WS.Cells(1, i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
    dRng.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 13
    Call ScrollToTop 

End If
End Sub
```

Currently, I get a ### in the First cell of the active Cell range. Than nothing beyond that.

Secondly, the Replace makes the change permanent. I just want to cover the value with something generic temporarily while the column is condensed to 5, then return to the actual value when all columns are expanded.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To replace a value with a piece of shorter text you can use `theRange.NumberFormat = ";;;""##"""` and then clear the format to restore the full values

Comment: ...that changes the value displayed in the cell but keeps the underlying value in place (you can still see it in the formula bar)

Comment: Thanks for that direction. I inserted the NumberFormat in to my loop, but it has inconsistent results. Some license Numbers are hidden completely, and some give the ###.
`Cells(row, i - 1).NumberFormat = ";;;""###"""`
They start out as "General" if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you give an example of one value that gets hidden and one value that gives "###" ?  What is the general pattern for your license numbers?

Comment: Maybe try `"###";"###";"###";"###"` You get the general idea though.

Comment: I think that; if the value had a Space, or Special Char like a "-" it would go blank.
I ended up going with an Interior.Color to show that the cell is occupied and NumberFormat = ";;;""""" to hide the characters.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Difficult for me to test without actual examples of the values you're trying to hide.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help, It definitely helped.  I do like the Color Coding more for this workbook, but I will use the number formatting again soon.